# TypeError: res.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to send two json but It doesn't work. It prints `TypeError: res.json is not a function` but I don't get why It happens. Is there any ideas? Thank you !!

```
app.post('/danger', function response(req, res) {
    let placeId = req.body.data;
    let option = {
      uri: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?',
      qs: {
        origin:`place_id:${placeId[0]}`, destination: `place_id:${placeId[1]}`,
        language: 'en', mode: 'walking', alternatives: true, key: APIKey
      }
    };
    rp(option)
      .then(function(res) {
        let dangerRate = dangerTest(JSON.parse(res), riskGrid);
        res.json({ data: [res, dangerRate]});
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error("Failed to get JSON from Google API", err);
      })
});
```

Comment: @BelminBedak Why would that matter?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because you're overwriting your `res` variable in the `.then` of your `rp` function:

```
app.post('/danger', function response(req, res) { //see, "res" here was being overwritten
   ..
   ..
   rp(option).then(function(response) { //change the variable name of "res" to "response" (or "turtles", who cares, just dont overwrite your up most "res")
```

Answer (score 19):

I got this error message because I had the arguments in the wrong order in the handler method. (amateur's fault)

Wrong order: (res, req)

```
app.get('/json', (res, req) => {
  res.json({
    "message": "Hello json"
  });
});
```

Right order: (req, res)

```
app.get('/json', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    "message": "Hello json"
  });
});
```

Comment: Works for me in typescript:
```typescript
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome to my API'
  });
});
```

Also, error comes first.

Answer (score 4):

`.json` isn't a function. Unless you are using a library that makes it one, JavaScript uses `JSON` (with two methods `.parse()` and `.stringify()` one of which you use in the line above).

If you are trying to set an object property by the name of `.json` then it would be:

```
res.json = {data: [res, dangerRate]};
```

Comment: As most people use express its worth pointing out this: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Answer (score 1):

With new httpClient libary, you don't need to call .json() method, Just use this simple map instead of the json method.

```
.map(res => res );
```

Answer (score 0):

check the sequence=>

If you have write nested res and you write (res,req) you get error.

Answer (score 0):

**order plays a very big role in `app.get('/',(req,res)=>{ });`**

**you can change the name instead of req and res but the second arg should be of res and the first should be of req**

like `app.get('/',(a,b)=>{ b.json({});`

```
above syntax is res.json({}) ,we are sending a json file at '/'

const express = require('express');
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const PORT = 80;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.post('/api/v1', (req, res) => {
    // const userName=req.body.name;
    res.send("<h1>done</h1>");
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.get("/api/v1/userdata", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        name: "your_Name",
        email: "your_Email",
        password: "hexed",
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("listening on port 80");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occured for me because of me using express.Router() instead of express() while initializing the app
I wrote the below line
const express = require("express");
const app = express().Router;

Correct way is to write this
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution to the `TypeError: res.json is not a function` error, arguments should be in the order (req, res)

On Typescript:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
const router = require('express').Router();
  
router.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      return res.json({ name: 'My Name' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).