# res.json is not a function - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this error using res.json to get the return of my function and this is code is been used em anothers places as wrote below, running fine.

```
async function getPlaylist(req, res, playlistId) {

  try {

    // const calltoken = await getToken()

    // const token = calltoken.data.access_token

    // console.log(token)

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'BQA0K9bKgBVn8xTp-yTsoaKs5VfS7EyjMIL03OEOy05wq08ZmLkNfqbbnsL_hFT1AV2FGN5tAQdeDV1X224', //token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    const url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/1j2L3DjzZ3SdN64r83Sblj?si=cuvOrPONSO6caE9XD6smEg'

    await axios.get(url, config)
      .then(function (response) {

        var playlist = response

        var items = playlist.data.tracks.items

        // console.log(items)

        const playlistfull = []

        items.forEach(index => {

          var playlistdata = {
            name: index.track.name,
            artists: index.track.album.artists[0].name,
            album: index.track.album.name,
            url: index.track.external_urls.spotify
          }

          playlistfull.push(playlistdata)

        })

        return res.json(playlistfull)

      })

  } catch (error) {

    return console.log(error)

  }
}
```

Comment: Why *should* `res.json` be a function? What **is** `res`? It's the second argument to `getPlaylist` but you haven't show us how that function is called so we can't know what the value actually is. Since it doesn't have a `json` method but you think it should be, that value probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: res.json is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075746/typeerror-res-json-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use in NodeJS 
Node's `res` give `parameter` to `function`

```js
const router = express.Router();
router
    .route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        const playlistId = 'asdf';
        getPlaylist(req, res, playlistId);
        return;
    });
```